# Obtaining vertices that getEdges() points to

Tags: maya, maya-api

I am trying to use `MItMeshPolygon::getEdges()` to obtain a list of edge coordinates.

However it returns a list of indices for the edges. Where can I find the corresponding data structure that the returned indices refer to?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the coordinates, just use `MItMeshPolygon::getPoints`:

```cpp
void MItMeshPolygon::getPoints (
    MPointArray &pointArray,
    MSpace::Space space = MSpace::kObject,
    MStatus *ReturnStatus = NULL)
```

> Retrieves the positions of the vertices on the current face/polygon
>   that the iterator is pointing to. Vertex positions will be inserted
>   into the given array and will be indexed using face-relative vertex
>   IDs (ie. ordered from 0 to (vertexCount of the face) - 1), which
>   should not be confused with the vertexIDs of each vertex in relation
>   to the entire mesh object.